# How can I get Matlab to use the variable value instead of name

Tags: matlab

In my code, I have a line that looks like this:

```
f=@(test) bf{i}(5);
```

where bf is a cell array with functions from str2func() stored in it, i is a variable storing an integer, and the 5 is the argument to pass to the function. How can I get matlab to evaluate the line using the current value of i? Right now when I display f it outputs:

```
@(test)bf{i}(5)
```

Lets say i=1, I want it to output:

```
@(test)bf{1}(5)
```

Although technically the bf{1} should also be replaced with whatever function is stored in bf{1}. How can I force matlab to evaluate the variables in this statement?

Comment: You are aware that the function handles keep their own copy of the variables? So changing i or bf later won't change the result.

Comment: I guess that basically makes what I asked impossible, you can make that an answer and I will accept it if you want

Comment: It doesn't make it impossible, just wanted to know make sure you understood function handles right.

Comment: when you say you want it to _Output_ `@(test)bf{1}(5)`. Do you mean that literally as in the _string representation_ of the function, or do you want the _numerical_ output produced by the 1st function in array `bf` with input value `5` ?

Comment: I want to be able to plug i into function call and get out the function that is stored in that location in bf, so if bf{1} is rectMath, then I would want the final value of f to be @(test)rectMath(5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a function handle, the workspace variables are copied and the expression is evaluated when you call the function handle (Typically not a problem in memory consumption, matlab stores only changes).

Now the problem is, to tell Matlab when to evaluate what part of the expression.
If you are aiming for a better performance, pre-evaluate all constant parts of the function. Let's say your function is `@(x)(g(3).*f(x))`, in this case matlab would evaluate `g(3)` on every call.

Instead use:

```
f=@(x)(x.^2)
g_3=g(3)
h=@(x)(g_3.*f(x))
```

Now having the constant parts evaluated, you want to see the constants instead of the variabe name. I know two ways to achieve this.

You can use the symbolic toolbox, basically converting the function handle to a symbolic function, then to a function handle again. This not only displays the constants, but also substitutes `f`. This is not possible for all functions.

```
>> matlabFunction(h(sym('x')))

ans = 

    @(x)x.^2.*4.2e1
```

Another possibility is to use eval:

```
h=eval(['@(x)',sprintf('%e',g_3),'.*f(x)'])
```

Pre-evaluating constant parts of the expressions as I did in the first step is typically recommendable, but both solutions to get the constant visible in your function handle aren't really recommendable. The first solution using `matlabFunction` only applies to some functions, while the second comes with all the disadvantages of `eval`.